# How to find the Laplace transform of $t\cos{t}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I need to find the Laplace transform of $f(t) = t \cos{t}$. I tried using the Taylor series expansion for $\cos{t}$ but I got stuck since the resulting expression is again a series which I could not simplify.

I would like to know if there is an easier method to find this transform without using Taylor series. I don't want the answer, just need to learn how to find it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

We have:

$$\mathcal{L}(\cos(t)) = \dfrac{s}{s^2+1}$$

$$\mathcal{L}(t \cos(t)) = -\dfrac{d}{ds} \left(\dfrac{s}{s^2+1}\right) = \dfrac{s^2-1}{(s^2+1)^2}$$

Are you familiar with the rule I am using?

If

$$\mathcal{L}(f(t)) = F(s)$$

Then

$$\mathcal{L}(t^nf(t)) = (-1)^n\dfrac{d^n}{ds^n}F(s)$$

Comment: Well no, I was not aware of that rule. How do you get it?

Comment: You might also find this instructive. For the Rule used, see: http://www.mathalino.com/reviewer/advance-engineering-mathematics/multiplication-power-t-laplace-transform

Comment: Thanks, very good reference.

Comment: Needs another and another + today.

Answer (score 0):

$\cal L\{t\cos t\}=-\dfrac{d}{ds}L\{\cos t\}=-\dfrac{d}{ds}\left(\dfrac{s}{s^2+1}\right)=\dfrac{s^2-1}{(s^2+1)^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#0000ff}{\large\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-st}\bracks{t\cos\pars{t}}\,\dd t}
=
\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}t\expo{\pars{-s + \ic}t}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=
\Re\braces{%
\left.t\,{\expo{\pars{-s + \ic}t} \over -s + \ic}\right\vert_{0}^{\infty}
-
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{\pars{-s + \ic}t} \over -s + \ic}\,\dd t}
=
\Re\braces{%
\left.-\,{1 \over -s + i}
{\expo{\pars{-s + \ic}t} \over - s + i}\right\vert_{0}^{\infty}}
=
\Re\bracks{{1 \over \pars{-s + \ic}^{2}}}
\\[3mm]&=
\Re\bracks{{\pars{-s - \ic}^{2} \over \pars{s^{2} + 1}^{2}}}
=
\Re\bracks{s^{2} + 2s\,\ic - 1 \over \pars{s^{2} + 1}^{2}}
=
\color{#0000ff}{\large{s^{2} - 1 \over \pars{s^{2} + 1}^{2}}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

We know $$L(t^n)=\frac{n!}{s^{n+1}}$$ for integer $n\ge0$

Using [Shifting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems) property,  $$L\{e^{at}f(t)\}=F(s-a)\text{ where } L\{f(t)\}=F(s)$$

$$\implies L\{e^{at}t^n\}=\frac{n!}{(s-a)^{n+1}}$$

Now, put $a=i=\sqrt{-1}$ to utilize [Euler's Formula](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler%27s_Formula)

$$\implies L\{e^{it}t^n\}=\frac{n!}{(s-i)^{n+1}}=\frac{n!(s+i)^{n+1}}{(s^2+1)^{n+1}}$$

Equate the real parts to find $L\left(\cos t\cdot t^n\right)$

Here $n=1$

Answer (score 0):

If you guys don't mind, I'm going to go ahead and post an additional way to get the solution.

Let $f(t) = t\cos t$. It 's clear that $f(0)=0$.

Now, note that $f^{\prime}(t) = \cos t - t\sin t$ and that $f^{\prime}(0)=1$.

Furthermore, we have that $f^{\prime\prime}(t) = -2\sin t - t\cos t$.

We now make use of the fact that $$\mathcal{L}\{f^{\prime\prime}(t)\} = s^2\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} - sf(0) -f^{\prime}(0)$$
to see that we have

$$\begin{aligned} s^2\mathcal{L}\{t\cos t\} - 1 = \mathcal{L}\{-2\sin t - t\cos t\} &\implies (s^2+1)\mathcal{L}\{t\cos t\} = -2\mathcal{L}\{\sin t\}+1\\ &\implies (s^2+1)\mathcal{L}\{t\cos t\} = \frac{s^2-1}{s^2+1} \\ &\implies \phantom{(s^2+1)}\mathcal{L}\{t\cos t\} = \frac{s^2-1}{(s^2+1)^2}\end{aligned}$$
which agrees with what everyone else found.