# Find the inverse Laplace transformation of $\frac{e^{-s}}{s+2}$

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

My question is: Find the function $f(t)$ that has the following Laplace transform
$$F(s)=\dfrac{e^{-s}}{s+2}$$
Thanks .

my try:I have find this [Find the inverse Laplace transformation of $\dfrac{s+1}{(s^2 + 1)(s^2 +4s+13)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424071/find-the-inverse-laplace-transformation-of-dfracs1s2-1s2-4s13)

Comment: We can utilize the formulae mentioned  in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/563897/how-to-find-the-laplace-transform-of-t-cost/563914#563914

Comment: Thank you,can you post your solution? because  I'm not sure  my result is correct.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have $$F(s)=\frac{1}{s+2}$$
The solution is easily $$f(t)=e^{-2t}$$
But,because you have a time translation: $$L\{f(t-a)\}=e^{-as}F(s)$$

The transform is $$f(t)=e^{-2(t-1)}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $\mathcal{L}\{u(t-a)\} = \dfrac{e^{-as}}{s}$ and thus by a shift theorem $\mathcal{L}\{e^{bt}u(t-a)\} = \dfrac{e^{-a(s-b)}}{s-b}$.